# paste in "vimL normal execution" the string located in a register memory

Tags: vim

How do I execute a command which involves a register data inside a vimL function?

say (as an example test case) I want to open a file whose direction string is in register z. During normal execution I could hit the keys:

```
:e <c-r>z<CR>   # CR is "carret return", <c-r>z is "paste registry z"
```

In vimL it gets complicated. I tried the following options and are not working.

```
fun! OpenFileInBrackets()
    exe 'normal! :e \<c-r>z'."\<cr>"
    exe 'normal! :e <c-r>z'."\<cr>"
    norm! :e <c-r>z<CR>
endfun
```

What are the options?

thank you!

Comment: My suggestion would be to use functions inside of vim scripts rather than their normal mode equivalents.  In this case, to get the value from a register, use `getreg()`.  A list of available functions can be found at `:help function-list`.

Comment: I like the idea; I didn't know about such function. However, I am still unable to open the file in the example. I don't know how to combine the new tool... I am definitely not fluent with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving my comment to an answer.

My suggestion would be to use functions inside of vim scripts rather than their normal mode equivalents. In this case, to get the value from a register, use `getreg()`.

Here's a quick example:

```
function OpenRegZ()
    let filename = getreg("z")
    execute "edit " . fnameescape(filename)
endfunction
```

A list of available functions can be found at `:help function-list`.

Edit: Added `fnameescape()` per the suggestion of `:help execute`.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, this implies using `execute` type statements rather than `norm`. Am I right?

Comment: If you're going to use variables in a normal command you need to execute the normal command.  See https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/9644/how-to-use-a-variable-in-the-expression-of-a-normal-command